# How does map take partial ownership though an immutable reference

Tags: dictionary, rust, iterator, borrow-checker

I am trying to write a function to find the value of a hand of cards. As part of this I need to check if the hand is a flush. My code for doing so is:

```rust
use itertools::Itertools;     // allows use of .all_equal()

fn find_hand_value(player_hand: Hand) {
    let is_flush: &bool = &player_hand.cards.map(|card| card.suit).iter().all_equal();
    // ... further checks
    println!("{:?}", player_hand)    // print takes ownership to represent further use of the hand
    // return hand value
}
```

However, if you attempt to run this code you will run into an error showing saying `player_hand.cards` has been partially moved due to the method call to `map`. Considering that the map is called on an immutable borrow of `player_hands` I do not understand how this is possible as it appears to be in direct contradiction of rust's borrowing rules.

Could someone please explain what is happening here and how/why it is possible? Thanks,

**For context:**

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Hand {
    cards: [Card; 5],
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Card {
    suit: Suit,
    value: Value,
}

#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Eq)]
enum Suit {
    Hearts,
    Diamonds,
    Spades,
    Clubs,
}

#[derive(Debug, Ord, PartialOrd, Eq, PartialEq)]
enum Value {
    Two,
    Three,
    Four,
    Five,
    Six,
    Seven,
    Eight,
    Nine,
    Ten,
    Jack,
    Queen,
    King,
    Ace,
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Considering that the map is called on an immutable borrow of player_hand

That's just not true. The `find_hand_value` owns the `player_hand`, and the [`map` function *on arrays*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.array.html#method.map) takes ownership of the array:

```rust
impl<T, const N: usize> [T; N]

pub fn map<F, U>(self, f: F) -> [U; N]
where
    F: FnMut(T) -> U,
```

There are two things that might be confusing here.

### You're not borrowing

First, you might be thinking this line:

```rust
&player_hand.cards.map(|card| card.suit).iter().all_equal()
```

takes a borrow on `player_hands.cards` and calls `map` on it. But that's not how this is parsed, this is actually:

```rust
&(player_hand.cards.map(|card| card.suit).iter().all_equal())
```

so just a (useless) borrow of the returned `bool` value. You can explicitly write:

```rust
(&player_hand.cards).map(|card| card.suit).iter().all_equal())
```

and then you'll get a different error, telling you that `map` *cannot* be called on a borrow:

```rust
error[E0508]: cannot move out of type `[Card; 5]`, a non-copy array
 --> src/main.rs:5:20
  |
5 |     let is_flush = (&player_hand.cards).map(|card| card.suit).iter().all_equal();
  |                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^---------------------
  |                    |                    |
  |                    |                    value moved due to this method call
  |                    cannot move out of here
  |                    move occurs because value has type `[Card; 5]`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
  |
note: `array::<impl [T; N]>::map` takes ownership of the receiver `self`, which moves value
```

### Wrong `map`

The other thing is that there is the [`map`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.map) that most people are familiar with that can be called on an `Iterator`, which can be obtained from a borrowed slice with [`iter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.iter). The fix here is to... move the calls around and start with `iter`:

```rust
player_hand.cards.iter().map(|card| card.suit).all_equal()
```

This *still* doesn't compile, because `Suit` is not copy so the map tries to move it, but this one is rather simple, just `derive(Clone, Copy)` on `Suit`.

Comment: Thank you very much, you got my thinking down to a T and that's a fantastic explanation of where I went wrong and how to fix it. One last thing, do you know of a way to check for a flush without taking taking ownership or copy/cloning values? I know the cost here is extremely minimal but it still seems wasteful to be assigning memory for a read-only operation.

Comment: just realised I can do it simply by making `card.suit` `&card.suit` thanks again for the great answer.

Comment: There's no real "copy" going on here. The `iter` on an array will do the obvious thing of going through indices from `0` to `len()-1`, borrowing the cards. The `Suit` is just an `enum` so "copy" in its context is just moving an integer between registers.

Comment: Actually, I plugged this into godbolt to see exactly what the compiler does and here it doesn't even loop. Since the array is always of size 5 it just unrols the 5 comparisons, xoring the enum values and checking for zero. (see https://godbolt.org/z/6G6PK8cnP, slightly modified because I can't use `itertools`)